# Phonegap and Sencha Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, extjs, cordova, touch

I just created an Xcode project with PhoneGap and copied my Sencha Touch files into the www-directory. If I compile it, it starts in the simulator as it should. But if I want to deploy it to my iPhone the app doesn't compile.

Looks like this: http://d.pr/i/DAZ1

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Which iPhone are you trying to deploy to?

Comment: I'm trying do deploy to an iPhone 4. I forgot to say that if I don't copy the Sencha files into the Xcode project it works fine on my phone.

Comment: It sorta looks like an architecture issue. From the image you posted looks like you're building for ARMv7s when iPhone 4 is ARMv7.

Comment: Ah I found my mistake. The iOS Deployment Target was set to the wrong one. My fault.